# Jquery finding patterns in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to find path information from a string using jquery and push the results into an array.

The string output looks like;

```
 "var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '270', '266'); 
 var path_a = rsr.path('M144.869,199c0,7.659-5.479,13.139-13.14,
 13.139 c-7.659,0-14.598-5.479-14.598-13.139s6.209-13.139,13.869-
 13.139S144.869,191.341,144.869,199z'); path_a.attr({fill: 'non .... etc"
```

I need to retrieve every occurrence of the path information with in rsr.path() ;

How would i go about achieving this? using $.each on my string with a regex?

thanks cam

Comment: can convert string to js using `eval()` but `eval()` is not good, might be better to figure out why script is in string in first place and see if it can't be changed to JSON instead, or just js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this worked..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('form.svg-convert').submit(function(event){

        var content = $(this).find('textarea').val();
        process(content);

        event.preventDefault();
    })
})


var process = function(c){

    var content = c,
        paths = [];

    var contentSplit = content.split('path(');
    contentSplit.shift(); 

    $.each(contentSplit,function(i,v){

        var path = v.split(')');
        path = path[0];
        paths.push(path);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will let you do this with a regular expression:

```
var s = " var rsr = Raphael('rsr', '270', '266'); var path_a = rsr.path('M144.869,199c0,7.659-5.479,13.139-13.14, 13.139 c-7.659,0-14.598-5.479-14.598-13.139s6.209-13.139,13.869- 13.139S144.869,191.341,144.869,199z'); path_a.attr({fill: 'non .... etc";

var regex = /M144\.869(.+?)869,199z/g;
var matches = regex.exec(s);
```

matches[0] then contains the capture group.

Comment: Hey Kyle, thanks for your reply, i've reworded the question, apologies it was a little misleading.